# Global implicit and local explicit localization. Is this possible?

Tags: .net, asp.net, localization

Can we set global implicit localization for control or local explicit localization?

Comment: Can you provide more details what you want ?

Comment: Muhammad Akhtar, Paweł Dyda has given good answer for my question.

Answer (score 1):

Are you Looking this `String Text = Resources.GlobalRes.KeyName` ? This will get the resource text from the Global Resources.

And if you want to get the value from the local Resource, then it will be 
`GetLocalResourceObject("yourkey").ToString();`

**Edit:** if you want to directly set the Gloabl Resource text to your label, do so as follows:

```
<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:GlobalRes, KeyName %>"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: No, I mean not magic way. I interesting can I wrote something like this: `<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="" meta:resourcekey="Label2Resource1"></asp:Label>` if Label2Resource1 located in App_GlobalResources, and `<asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:LocalResource, String1 %>"></asp:Label>` if LocalResource located in App_LocalResources.

Comment: You want to set the Global resources to your label text ?

Comment: that should be like <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources:GlobalRes, KeyName %>"></asp:Label> check my edit part of answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use implicit Localization, you have to use App_LocalResources, so "global" is not possible nor needed actually.

You can obviously use explicit Localization with App_LocalResources, although I see no benefit here.